# Communication from ably to MQTT

Tags: mqtt, ably-realtime

I wanted to know if there is an example to do it the other way round, that is from Ably to MQTT.
I need this for my IoT application where I am trying to send an instruction to change the sensor value from the webpage -> ably-> MQTT broker-> my Arduino and wanted to try an example to implement the data transfer from Ably to MQTT. I was unable to find a reference example to build my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward with Ably. Most connections are bi-directional, so ably messages are translated into MQTT messages automatically.

You don't actually need a broker as we do that part as well.

Here is a sample project that does something similar with an arduino:
https://github.com/ably-labs/LED-Matrix-Jumper

There are a few other Adurino demos in the same [Ably labs github org](https://github.com/orgs/ably-labs/repositories)

Comment: Thanks Ben for the help! I will give that a shot.